# Interpreting logit coefficients that have been converted to probability

Tags: logistic, interpretation

Let's say I run the following specification:

```
fit <- glm(outcome ~ treatment + gender + language + age, data = date_restriction, family = "binomial")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    treatment       gender      language        age  
   -3.75205      0.29006      0.13278     -0.44440     -0.00104
```

The resulting coefficient on `treatment` is .290.  I would like to convert this to probability, so I run the following function:

```
logit2prob <- function(logit){
  odds <- exp(logit)
  prob <- odds / (1 + odds)
  return(prob)
}

logit2prob(.290)

>> 0.5719961
```

I am interpreting this to mean that individuals in the treatment condition are 57.1% more likely to do (outcome) than individuals in the control condition.  But this seems highly unusual.  Is this "%" interpretation consistent with the probability conversion?

Furthermore, I have been given advice to never convert logit coefficients to probabilities, and to instead compute average marginal effects.  Doing so yields the following:

```
>margins(fit) 
 treatment 
 0.007139
```

Why does this appear so small relative to the .57 probability estimate above?  Is it because marginal effects are interpreted in terms of percentage *points*, and not percent? What is the most appropriate way to interpret this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the coefficient for a predictor in a logistic regression is not quite what you take it to be. It's the *change* in logit of the outcome for a one-unit change in the predictor. How much that changes the probability of the outcome depends on the intercept of the model (for the case when treatment = 0 in your example) and any other predictors that might be included.

So when you use `logit2prob` to convert to a probability you have to include all those other coefficients. For example, if the intercept in your model is 0, the probability of outcome in the control group is `logit2prob(0+0)` or 0.5; being in the treatment group increases that probability to `logit2prob(0+0.29)` or your value of 0.57. That's only a 7 percentage-point difference.

If the control group was unlikely to have the outcome (say, intercept = -2 for about a 12% probability of outcome) then your coefficient for `treatment` changes that to `logit2prob(-2+0.29)` = 0.153, or about a 15% probability for about a 3 percentage-point change.

This dependence of the outcome probability on the intercept (and on values of other predictors and their coefficients) is a major reason why you have been warned, quite rightly, not to try to convert logistic regression *coefficients* to probabilities. Converting logistic regression *predictions* from the logit value returned by the model to a probability, on the other hand, is fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have just added in intercept and covariate information.  Based on this post, I assume I would do: ```logit2prob(-3.75205 + .290) = 0.0304```  Comparing that to the probability of being in the control group ```logit2prob(-3.75205)``` yields 0.022, or a difference of ```0.0074```, which is very close to the output from the margins command.  Does this look right?  I interpret this as essentially <1 percentage point difference?  

Is it also fair to say that the treatment has about 33% higher odds of the outcome than the control? ```exp(.290) = 1.336427```

Comment: @Parseltongue the interpretations in your comment seem to be OK. I would caution you, however, that many people (myself included) don't have a good instinctive understanding of changes in odds or odds ratios. I'm much more comfortable with changes in probabilities. One example: the same 33% higher odds of the outcome in the treatment group would mean a 7 percentage-point difference if your intercept had been 0, versus a 0.7% percentage-point difference with your intercept of -3.75.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks Ed.  I suppose that's the reason I've been cautioned against using odds ratios.  I'm wondering if it's valid to interpret a "33% higher odds of the outcome" as a "33% higher likelihood of the outcome."  Are those compatible? They strike me as slightly different (the latter seems to connote probability), but I've seen % changes in odds ratios interpreted in this fashion

Comment: @Parseltongue "likelihood" has an important specific [technical meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) in statistics, so I would recommend against using that word loosely when other words are available. But that word is certainly more closely related to probabilities than to odds, as you note..